# Is there a guarantee that no signals are delivered from a different thread after QObject::disconnect()?

Tags: qt, thread-safety, signals-slots

I am not thinking of the problem that queued signals are still delivered in the receiving thread after `disconnect()`, instead:

Consider the case that a `Sender` object is generating signals in thread 1 and there is a `Receiver` object in thread 2 which has a slot that is connected to `Sender`'s signal via a `Qt::DirectConnection`.

Now, in `Receiver::~Receiver()`, I need to make sure that no signals are still delivered while the object is already (maybe partially) destructed. Because the connection is direct, the slot could be invoked in thread 1 at any time and could in particular happen between destruction of `Receiver`'s specific attributes and destruction of the base `QObject` which will also disconnect signals. So, my question boils down to:

Is it enough to disconnect `Sender` and `Receiver` objects in thread 2 before destruction of the `Receiver` object, or do I need to make sure that no signals are emitted in thread 1 during the `disconnect()` call?

I am thinking of the case where thread 1 is in the middle of emitting the signal, e.g. right at the top of executing the receiving slot and right at that moment, in thread 2, the `disconnect()` call is done. If `disconnect()` waits (via a mutex) for thread 1 to finish delivering the signal before doing the disconnect and blocking further signal deliveries, everything would be fine but I am not sure that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `disconnect()` and `connect()` are using mutexes for protection.

These are the first lines of the `disconnect()` function:

```
bool QMetaObjectPrivate::disconnect(const QObject *sender, int signal_index,
                                    const QObject *receiver, int method_index,
                                    DisconnectType disconnectType)
{
    if (!sender)
        return false;

    QObject *s = const_cast<QObject *>(sender);

    QMutex *senderMutex = signalSlotLock(sender);
    QMutex *receiverMutex = receiver ? signalSlotLock(receiver) : 0;
    QOrderedMutexLocker locker(senderMutex, receiverMutex);
```

And here are the first lines of the `connect()` function:

```
bool QMetaObjectPrivate::connect(const QObject *sender, int signal_index,
                                 const QObject *receiver, int method_index, int type, int *types)
{
    QObject *s = const_cast<QObject *>(sender);
    QObject *r = const_cast<QObject *>(receiver);

    QOrderedMutexLocker locker(signalSlotLock(sender),
                               signalSlotLock(receiver));
```

If you check the [`QObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html) documentation you can see that :

> Note: All functions in this class are reentrant, but **connect(),
>   connect(), disconnect(), and disconnect() are also thread-safe.**

**EDIT**

When a signal is emitted the QMetaObject::activate function is called which locks the sender's object mutex:

```
void QMetaObject::activate(QObject *sender, const QMetaObject *m, int local_signal_index,
                           void **argv)
{
     ...
     QMutexLocker locker(signalSlotLock(sender));
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw that. What I am not sure about is whether the delivery of the signal is protected using the same mutexes.